# Good recommendations for solving PDE's by integral transforms

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, integral-transforms

I look for good books on solving partial diffrential equations (PDE's) using integral transforms specially Fourier and laplace transforms.

Do you have any recommendations for such books? I don't look for a book concerned with the theory, rather, with the methods itself (a suitable book for a physicist not a mathematician). So , the more solved examples there are, the better it will be!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some online resources that are decent:

1. [Fourier transform to solve PDEs](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/pdeft.pdf)
2. [Laplace transform to solve PDEs](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/ttu/s10/m3351_s10/c15_laplace_trans_pdes.pdf)
3. [Fourier transform methods for PDEs article](http://pubs.sciepub.com/ijpdea/2/3/2/)
4. [Another on Laplace transforms](http://www.math.vt.edu/people/russell/m2k_fsp_laplace.pdf)
5. [Another Journal Article on Laplace transforms](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2012-78-7/3/3.pdf)

I haven't found some of the resources I have used before but I will update if I do.